# Rest Api Http Status codes

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Should I use internal http status code like twitter or use the standard http status codes

internal Http status code example:

```
737 refers to 404
```

or should I use 404 and what if I had a lot of responses which return a 404 but with different messages?

Comment: IMO you should return standard status codes with the response and have your custom codes in the body.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a REST api from scratch, I would recommend the following:

1. Use HTTP status codes appropriately.
2. Use a standard response body to send more details about errors. [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) is a great choice.

I'm not sure if you need internal status codes. Might depend on the language. Most languages have exceptions, so there's probably no need to have codes in addition to exceptions.

Comment: But in my application there will be some cases like:
1. location not found
2. ID not found
So I have two 404 status codes with different meaning

Comment: That's why I suggested '2' in my list.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot.